# Unprotect Quantity does not work at the first time

Tags: functions

With a fresh kernel, run

```
Unprotect[Quantity]; 
Quantity[x_Around, "DimensionlessUnit"] := x;
```

gives

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Quantity in x_Around is Protected.

But run it a second time, the warning disappears.

Why doesn't `Unprotect` work at the first time?

Comment: Works on MMA version 13.3

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for testing. But I just tested in 13.3. It has the same behaviour as 13.2

Comment: Strange, I do not get an error message. I have Windows 10.

Comment: It works without errors on the cloud as well.

Comment: @MarcoB I do not know what is going on. But it is indeed happens on my computer https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FU4sCAEBBNByCUg2Vu2IBJRWjxpq3mXL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The duplicate question isn't totally clear about the solution. You want: `Quantity; Unprotect[Quantity]; ...; Protect[Quantity];`. The first use of the symbol must be outside of the `Unprotect` invocation.

Comment: This problem only reproduces for me in initialization cells on a fresh kernel. So the "I do not get error message" comments are because of that.

Comment: I also wonder whether `^=` instead of `:=` is better at both expressing intent and maintaining evaluation speed. The latter IIRC adds a global rule, whereas the former adds an upvalue to Quantity and doesn't modify the global rule set. I'd thus suggest `Quantity[x_Around,"DimensionlessUnit"]^:=x; UpValues[Around]` vs. `Quantity[x_Around,"DimensionlessUnit"]:=x; DownValues[Quantity]`.